# What's the Django way to render a tree of folders and files?

Tags: django, os.walk

Still a newbie...

In my view I have used os.walk to list user files available:

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(docroot, topdown=True):
    #...do something here
```

Now I want to render these results via the template.
How would **you** do that?

What goes here?

```
#...do something here
```

And what goes in the template?

Comment: I really appreciate Elf's answer below but I'll keep this open a while.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a tree structure, which a directory is, then you can turn your for() loop into a generator and have it recursively call itself as needed.  You'll need two templates (one for files, one for folders), and a view that creates generators for each folder.

Here's a file template:

```
<li>{{ file }}</li>
```

Here's a folder template:

```
<li>{{ file }}<ul>{% for f in subfiles %}{{ f }}{% endfor %}</ul></li>
```

In your main template, you need a starting list for the root folder:

```
<ul>{% for f in subfiles %}{{ f }}{% endfor %}</ul>
```

And here's the view.  This example uses Treebeard, but the logic for branches/leaves is the same as folders/files:

```
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    def index_maker():
        def _index(root):
            files = os.listdir(root)
            for mfile in files:
                t = os.path.join(root, mfile)
                if os.path.isdir(t):
                     yield loader.render_to_string('demo/p_folder.html',
                                                   {'file': mfile,
                                                    'subfiles': _index(os.path.join(root, t))})
                     continue
                 yield loader.render_to_string('demo/p_file.html',
                                               {'file': mfile})
        return _index('/home/httpd/htdocs')

    c = index_maker()
    return render_to_response('demo/index.html',
                               {'subfiles': c})
```

Each node is either a file or a folder.  Folders have names, so when rendering a folder we pass that and the list of entries (children) in that folder.  The `_index()` function, by using `yield`, returns not the list of subfiles but a generator which will produce the results when called by the `for` loop within the template.  This becomes a nifty dance between `_index()` and the template renderers.

Comment: That is one of the clearest answers I have met on the site - :) - it really illustrates how the templates/view relationship can work with the data structures. I was trying to understand that.

Comment: Dizzley: Since I wasn't familiar with os.walk, I didn't appreciate how different it was from a recursive solution.  It wouldn't work with my rendering of a tree; there has to be a different solution for using it.  So I've edited my example to show how this would work using listdir/isdir.  I've tested this and it works.

Comment: I appreciated the recursive solution and could see (roughly) how to adapt it... but you just did all the work. :D

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a big fan of generators and iterators, and use them a lot to wrap querysets and the like in convertors, humanizers, etc.  I've never been happy with the way "return" returns a value, but yield returns a function that is-a-generator that returns values.  It takes an extra leap of brain to recall that.  But they can be made to do miraculous things.

Comment: Amazing! 
Great solution, used it in the tree-view of the java source browser @ MobSF